# Increase memory of Umbraco Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to upload a large file in umbraco application. Now this application should be running at the background. But when I try to upload use process a large video like 700mb I get an error saying

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Some suggested to increase the IIS configuration to be 64bits but I only have the `.sln` file and I didn't setup any IIS configuration to make the application run. So I would assume that the configuration like memories is within the application settings and not in the IIS (which I don't know how it's being linked). Honestly I'm really new to this C#.net thing and Umbraco and I'm just trying to process large video files.

Any idea on how can I get pass the `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Just take into consideration that I didn't setup any IIS and I just run the given `.sln` file in Visual Studio.

Would really appreciate your help on this. Cheers

Comment: Compile it as x64 and ensure that "prefer 32 bits" is unchecked in the configuration options of the project.

Comment: @Gusman sorry for the noob question how do I do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: 1-Change to x64: you will have a drop-down on the top-left of VS which will say "Any CPU", open it and select "Configuration manager" or whatever it says in your version. A new window with two dropdown lists will appear, the right one will say "Any CPU", open it and select "New", Choose "x64" and "copy" and accept it. 2-Now you must uncheck the "prefer 32 bit", right-click the project node on the solution explorer, click properties, select the "Compilation" tab and uncheck the option. Now the project will work only on 64bits machines but it will allow to use a lot more memory.

Comment: @Gusman thanks dude... I found the platform dropdown and selected to x64 and left the other solution to Any CPU and now I was able to save the file. Now my only problem is why when using MediaService.CreateMedia and using the media type as File I'm getting an error of supplied alias: umbracoWidth which obviously it doesn't have a width since it's a file and not an image

Comment: That's a totally different question, create a new one.